# Filter column list based on another column in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, filter, multiple-columns

In Python, I have a dataset like this below, where `column1` and `column2` are objects and not strings:

```
data = {'id':  ['first_value', 'first_value', 'second_value', 'third_value'],
    'column1': [a0, a0 a1, a2, a87],
    'column2': [a0=4, a0=2;a1=8;a7=9, a2=0, a33=9]
    }
```

And I want to keep on '**`column2`**' the values that:

a.  are also in **`'column1'`**.
b.  the values that are bigger than zero after the "=" sign on **`'column2'`** (so, for example, `'a2=0'` will be removed from the result because is zero `(...=0)`, while `a1=8` will stay because it's 8 `(...=8)`)

Therefore in this case my result would be:

```
data = {'id':  ['first_value', 'first_value'],
        'column1': ['aO', 'a0;a1'],
        'column2': ['a0=4', 'a0=2;a1=8']
        }
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you clarify point b: what are the values and how can they be bigger than 0 if they are strings. Trying to make sense of your result, but it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Ah sorry! Thanks for the feedback! It's like "a2=0" on 'column2' is zero, so it should be removed from the result. I will update the post :)

Comment: Can you show your attempts, or what you tried?

Comment: in the desired output, why do you have `a7` in `column1` when it wasn't there before?

Comment: Sure, on the beginning I did data = data.astype(dtype={'column2': 'string'}) so I will change my column from object to string. Then I tried to: for each row of the dataset iterating for each value on column1 to check if the values on column1 were on column2. The problem is that even for like a dataset with 100 rows this is too slow, so it's sure that is not the solution

Comment: Then I decided to try to put all on strings and try to check if the substrings of column1 were on the substrings of column2, moreover I could not manage to do this yet (still trying)

Comment: because I cannot manage to transform "column1" in list (using to_list()) or into a string (using data.astype(dtype={'column1': 'string'})). Moreover column2 I could do it :) So before testing this "string comparison" idea for the solution I need to actually transform the data into a list of strings... and i could not figure it out how yet

Comment: Following your latest edit, should `a0 a1` be comma-separated?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `apply` on rows

```py
def filter_column(row):
    keys = row['column1'].split(' ')
    dicts = dict([kv.split('=') for kv in row['column2'].split(';')])
    lists = [f'{k}={v}' for k, v in dicts.items()
             if k in keys and int(v) > 0]
    return ';'.join(lists)

df['column3'] = df.apply(filter_column, axis=1)
```

```
print(df)

             id column1         column2    column3
0   first_value      a0            a0=4       a0=4
1   first_value   a0 a1  a0=2;a1=8;a7=9  a0=2;a1=8
2  second_value      a2            a2=0
3   third_value     a87           a33=9

------------

print(df[df['column3'].ne('')])

            id column1         column2    column3
0  first_value      a0            a0=4       a0=4
1  first_value   a0 a1  a0=2;a1=8;a7=9  a0=2;a1=8
```

Comment: Hello! Thak you for your answer! I am having a problem when doing this because I have applied data['column2'].agg(lambda x: ';'.join(map(str, x))) to transform my "column2" into a string with ";" as separators moreover I am having ";" on the end of my column2, like: "a0=2;a1=8;a7=9;". I tried to change your code to for kv in row['keyPrefixDocCounts'].split(';')][:-1] (adding a [:-1] to the end), but this does not solve the issue. Any ideas? :)

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira I couldn't reproduce, but you can use `print` to see what's happening. You can also use `df['column2'].str.strip(';')` to strip the tailing `;`.

Answer (score 1):

For your problem, it seems easier to use a loop. Create sets from `column1` values, and dictionaries from `column2` values; then traverse both together using `zip` and identify common keys and see if the value under those keys are zero or not:

```
out = []
for col1, col2 in zip(({*x.split(';')} for x in df['column1']), 
                      (dict([kv.split('=') for kv in x.split(';')]) for x in df['column2'])):
    inner = []
    s = col2.keys() & col1
    while s:
        k = s.pop()
        if col2[k] != '0':
            inner.append(f"{k}={col2[k]}")
    out.append(';'.join(inner))
df['column2'] = out
out = df[df['column2']!='']
```

Output:

```
            id column1    column2
0  first_value      a0       a0=4
1  first_value   a0;a1  a0=2;a1=8
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer, it's ver smart! :) How did you manage to transform 'column1' from [a0, a0 a1, a2, a87] to a list separated by ";" where you can iterate like a dictionary?

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira it’s the first generator expression inside zip: `list({*x.split(';')} for x in df['column1'])`

Comment: but 'column1' do not have ";" ^^'

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira it was there before in your sample. You seem to have replaced it with `' '` now. So replace `({*x.split(';')} for x in df['column1'])` by `({*x.split()} for x in df['column1'])` and it will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you! Finally with your ideas I did this: data['column1'] = data['column1'].str.split(" ")
data['column1'] = data['column1'].agg(lambda x: ';'.join(map(str, x)))
data.update(a[['column1']].applymap('{}'.format)) and it's working like a charm! I've also debugged your code to understand better and I think I got it! Thank you :)

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira No worries. Glad you got a working code. FYI, even though my code is longer (I still think it's very readable though), it's more efficient than `apply` on `axis=1`. For example, my answer is ~5.5 times faster than the other answer. For small datasets, the difference won't make a difference but if your data has more than 100000 rows, it's going to be noticeable.